# Should a private virtual LAN be filtered

Tags: iptables, firewall, virtual-network

I'm a dev trying to learn others things and my current objective is to create a "virtual" lan on an ESXi host.

I've created a VM which work as the LAN gateway to the WAN and some VM that are exclusively on LAN.

I configured my iptables and I can access WAN from every LAN VM, I can also access apache server on a LAN VM from WAN.

My configuration seems correct and by default my policy is on DROP and I accept from WAN only wanted packets.

My question is about the LAN,

I'll illustrate by an example :

From my computer on the WAN i can SSH the VM1 (Which is the bridge between WAN & LAN) and from VM1 I can SSH LAN VMs.

Should I accept that from a LAN VM (except VM1) I can SSH to other LAN VM ?

I took SSH as an example but the question is more about if I should Policy DROP every VM and manually manage to accept what I need on each even on the LAN.

The WAN Input filtering can help to deal with intrusion issues, but is a LAN filtering "needed" to avoid propagation of an intrusion from a VM to another ?

Comment: https://www.itworldcanada.com/article/trusted-insiders-are-now-the-most-serious-security-threat/401284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is a LAN filtering "needed" to avoid propagation of an intrusion from a VM to another ?

Allowing lateral movement is a policy decision that you make. In general, denying any traffic that is not needed is better security. Trendy terms for this are micro-segmentation and zero trust networks.

For an overview of VM network security, have look at [NIST SP 800-125B Secure Virtual Network Configuration for Virtual Machine (VM) Protection](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-125B.pdf). It mentions firewalls, VLANs, and overlays. Note that the complete picture of network security goes beyond one VM.

[VMWare will be happy to tell you how their NSX product does micro-segmentation.](https://blogs.vmware.com/networkvirtualization/2016/06/micro-segmentation-defined-nsx-securing-anywhere.html/) Because of the central policy you can state that VM1 can talk to the WAN and one other host but no one else. There are alternatives, just stating that firewall configs do not have to be built by hand.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm gonna have a look at this pdf asap. Actually I'm trying to do that on a local server before doing it on a Dedidacted server I'm gonna rent but I wanna be confident enough before doing anything. More than a secure reason, I'm thinking that applying a full denying and allowing only needed could help me have a better overview of how my VMs are interacting with each others.

Comment: It is true that a default deny host level firewall is one line of defense. Just be aware of the other areas to apply security, either a network you see the physical layer, or VPC in the cloud where you build a private network with APIs. Just a VM ("VPS") which probably only gives you Internet access tends to not expose much at all of the network to you the consumer.